# Hoeffding Tree building: What is the use of $X_{\emptyset}$ in the pseudo-code?

Tags: machine-learning, cart

In the original paper of (Domingos and Hulton, 2000) where they introduce the [Very Fast Decision Tree learner](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~pedrod/papers/kdd00.pdf), Table 1 shows the procedure of building the Hoeffding Tree.

[image: outline algorithm for learning a Hoeffding tree]

At line 2 of the procedure, it introduces a symbol $X_{\emptyset}$, and $G_1(X_{\emptyset})$ is obtained "by predicting the most frequent class in $S$". What does this mean?

> Domingos, Pedro, and Geoff Hulten. "Mining high-speed data streams."
>   Proceedings of the sixth ACM SIGKDD international conference on
>   Knowledge discovery and data mining. ACM, 2000.

Answer (score 0):

Remember $G$ is the split evaluation function (i.e. information gain or Gini impurity) and $X_{\emptyset}$ is the null feature. The null feature $X_{\emptyset}$ is essentially establishing a threshold that needs to be met in order for the node to be split. As described in the algorithm a node is only split if $X_a \neq X_\emptyset$ and 
$$G_l(X_a) − G_l(X_b) > \epsilon \text{ or } \epsilon < \tau.$$
What is meant exactly by

> $G_1(X_\emptyset)$  is obtained "by predicting the most frequent class
>   in S"

depends on your choice of $G$. Suppose you are testing the feature $X$ as a candidate for splitting. Let's say $X$ is the attribute gender in your dataset, $X$ has two categories male and female, and suppose male are more frequent. If $G$ was information gain then we can compute information gain in general by:
$$IG(S, X)  = H(S) - H(S|X)$$
then I think $G_1(X_\emptyset)$ would mean
$$ G_1(X_\emptyset) = H(S) - H(S|X=male).$$